# Getting error when editing exist excel xlsx file with apache poi in Java ,How to solve this error

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

```
public static void SetCellValue(int sheetNum, String coordinant, String newValue) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\s.aga\\Desktop\\Reporting\\Ovs.xlsx"));
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(sheetNum);
        CellReference cellReference = new CellReference(coordinant);
        Row row = sheet.getRow(cellReference.getRow());
        Cell cell = row.getCell(cellReference.getCol());
        cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        cell.setCellValue(newValue);
        fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\s.aga\\Desktop\\Reporting\\Ovs.xlsx"));
        fis.close();
        workbook.write(fos);
        System.out.println("Done :" + coordinant);
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Package should contain a content type part [M1.13]
    at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:41)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:204)
    at utils.Utils.SetCellValue(Utils.java:54)
    at reporting.Reporting.doReporting(Reporting.java:108)
    at reporting.Reporting.main(Reporting.java:250)
Caused by: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Package should contain a content type part [M1.13]
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.getPartsImpl(ZipPackage.java:178)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.getParts(OPCPackage.java:662)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:269)
```

Comment: used jars:
poi-3.9
poi0ooxml3.9
xmlbeans2.3
poi-ooxml-schemas 3.7 beta

Comment: Thanks Jens. 
My file is protected with password ,i solve this problem remove forgotten password below link:

https://uknowit.uwgb.edu/page.php?id=28850